# can a service account be used to run a powershell script that interacts with an object

Tags: powershell

Can a service account be used to run a powershell script when the script interacts with objects it's displaying?  The script accesses a website, signs in and downloads a file.

Comment: That depends on *how* the interaction is done. `Invoke-WebRequest` is not interactive. Manipulating a browser (ill-advised) *is*, and doing that from a non-interactive session may or may not work, but is in any case terrible to troubleshoot if it doesn't. How are you planning to invoke the script, anyhow -- an actual service, or a scheduled task that runs a PowerShell script? The latter is a lot more manageable than the former.

Comment: a scheduled task that runs every day

Comment: navigating to the website $ie.navigate(https:xxxx)

Comment: I was told it wouldn't work because the script interacts with objects it's displaying and it's running it remotely and there is no interactive desktop.  I am very new to powershell and thought this would be a good automation and now hearing it won't work.

Comment: In many cases, you can access a website, sign in and download a file *without* using a browser -- it's a matter of sending the correct HTTP requests and saving cookies. Automating a browser is really only required if the site cannot run without JavaScript (since that needs a browser to run it). If that is the case, the script may or may not run from a scheduled task -- try it and see.